# I have written a trigger. But I have got an error while using the case statement

Tags: mysql

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `customersh`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `customersh` AFTER UPDATE ON `customers` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF old.customer_status_id !=new.customer_status_id  THEN
    INSERT INTO customers_h (
    status_changed_date,
    status_changed_by,
    loan_request_initial_id,
    verification_approval_id,
    ) VALUES
    ( 
    old.status_changed_date,
    old.status_changed_by,
    (CASE WHEN old.customer_status_id IN (2,3,4) AND new.customer_status_id IN (5,7,3,4)  
    THEN SELECT MAX(loan_request_initial_id) FROM loan_request_initial 
    WHERE customer_id = old.customer_id ELSE NULL END),

    old.verification_approval_id,
    );
END IF;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(loan_request_initial_id) FROM loan_request_initial ' at line 106

Please help me in resolving this error. Case Statement might be wrong.

Comment: plsql is used in `oracle`  not `mysql`

Comment: Remove comma after verification_approval_id and old.verification_approval_id

Answer (score 0):

Check your brackets properly

```
CASE WHEN old.customer_status_id IN (2, 3, 4)
  AND new.customer_status_id IN (5, 7, 3, 4) THEN (
    SELECT
      MAX(loan_request_initial_id)
    FROM
      loan_request_initial
    WHERE
      customer_id = old.customer_id
  ) ELSE NULL END
```